# Flask - sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) Not a boolean value: 'False'

Tags: python, json, flask, visual-studio-code, postman

I want to get the Default value of **OnlineAvailability** as **True**. By default, all Doctors will have all Slot Timings Available.

If I give the JSON Body data in **Postman** and **POST** the data:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/online

```
{
    "OnlineTimeSlot": "18:30"
}
```

Here, OnlineAvailability is being set to `true` by default and I get the message:

```
{
    "message": "New Time Slot, 18:30 added!"
}
```

When I **GET** the data, it shows:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/online/16

```
{
    "OnlineScheduleId": 16,
    "OnlineTimeSlot": "18:30",
    "OnlineAvailability": true
}
```

---

But,
If I want to give the OnlineAvailability as `false` and **POST** the data *or* If I want to update the existing Timings Data using the **PUT** method in Postman JSON body:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/online

```
{
    "OnlineTimeSlot": "18:30",
    "OnlineAvailability": false
}
```

Then, I am getting the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) Not a boolean value: 'False'
> [SQL: INSERT INTO "OnlineSchedules" ("OnlineTimeSlot", "OnlineAvailability") VALUES (?, ?)]
> [parameters: [{'OnlineTimeSlot': '18:30', 'OnlineAvailability': 'False'}]]
> // Werkzeug Debugger

---

How do I change the default value from `true` to `false` or upload a new Time Slot with OnlineAvailability as false without getting the above error? *(The value should be recognised as a Boolean Value instead of a String)*

*online.py --> models*

```
# omitted code

class OnlineScheduleModel(db.Model):
    
    # omitted code

    OnlineTimeSlot = db.Column(db.String(500), unique=True, nullable=False)
    OnlineAvailability = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True, server_default="true")

    def __init__(self, OnlineTimeSlot, OnlineAvailability):
        self.OnlineTimeSlot = OnlineTimeSlot
        self.OnlineAvailability = OnlineAvailability

    def json(self):
        return {"OnlineScheduleId": self.OnlineScheduleId, "OnlineTimeSlot": self.OnlineTimeSlot, "OnlineAvailability": self.OnlineAvailability}

# ommitted code
```

*online.py --> resources*

```
# omitted code

class OnlineScheduleInfo(Resource):

    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

    parser.add_argument("OnlineTimeSlot", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("OnlineAvailability", required=False)

    # omitted code
    @cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
    def post(self):
        data = OnlineScheduleInfo.parser.parse_args()
        schedule = OnlineScheduleModel(**data)
        if OnlineScheduleModel.find_by_timeslot(data['OnlineTimeSlot']):
            return {"message": "A timeslot '{}' already exists".format(data['OnlineTimeSlot'])}, 400
        # omitted code

        schedule.save_to_db()
        
        # omitted code

        return {"message": "New Time Slot, {} added!".format(data['OnlineTimeSlot'])}, 200
  
    @cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
    def put(self):
        data = OnlineScheduleInfo.parser.parse_args()
        schedule = OnlineScheduleModel.find_by_timeslot(data['OnlineTimeSlot'])
        if schedule is None:
            schedule = OnlineScheduleModel(**data)
        else:
            schedule.OnlineAvailability = data["OnlineAvailability"]
        schedule.save_to_db()
        return {"message": "schedule, {} Updated!".format(data['OnlineTimeSlot'])}, 200
```

Basically, My requirement is that I should be able to **POST** or **PUT** data with OnlineAvailability as `false`, and I should get the output in Postman for **GET**:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/online/16

```
{
    "OnlineScheduleId": 16,
    "OnlineTimeSlot": "18:00",
    "OnlineAvailability": false
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm not sure of how familiar you are with Python, but its boolean true and false are represented by keywords with very specific spelling requirements. Take a look at your post and put request bodies, closely, I think I may have spotted the issue.

Comment: The boolean values are correct. In Python the first letter is Caps and the rest is small (True, False) whereas, in JSON, it is complete lower case (true, false). I believe that there is nothing wrong with the Boolean values mentioned, as they show no errors in VS-Code or in Postman.

Comment: Ah, you are right about the values, but I was looking through the docs for Flasks reqparse and think I found an answer. Will post it shortly.

Comment: I realize that I trimmed too much and the edit queue is full. Should have left some of the app configuration code in app.py. That information was needed to tell me that you were using sqlite3, reminding me about the different representations of boolean true/false in various engines: (0,1), ("true", "false"), etc. I'll leave this comment here until I can fix my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small change in the code mentioned by [nstvnsn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11620108/nstvnsn),
Flask-RESTPlus is no longer being maintained.

So, instead, we can use flask_restx.

```
from flask_restx import inputs

parser.add_argument("OnlineAvailability", required=False, type=inputs.boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding an argument to the parser, you can leave out the type argument for simple primitive types. For boolean, you may need to declare it for wider boolean handling. Different databases handle boolean values differently.

If you look at the docs for sqlite3, which is the engine your app is using, it stores boolean values as 0 for false and 1 for true. The parser needs to know that the added argument is a boolean so it can parse the python native boolean type.

```python
from flask_restplus import inputs

parser.add_argument('OnlineAvailability', required=False, type=inputs.boolean)
```

To confirm this, I hacked together an app to reproduce the problem by using the code you provided:

[image: cURL POST in Terminal]

[image: cURL POST Error]

I added the type argument to the `parser.add_argument` function call and the same post request through cURL works:

[image: cURL POST Success]

Also, looking through the docs for Flask_restplus.reqparse.RequestParser (which is considered deprecated past 2.0, their docs mention it being replaced with a better alternative like marshmallow):

> Warning
>
> The whole request parser part of Flask-RESTPlus is slated for removal and will be replaced by documentation on how to integrate with other packages that do the input/output stuff better (such as marshmallow). This means that it will be maintained until 2.0 but consider it deprecated. Don’t worry, if you have code using that now and wish to continue doing so, it’s not going to go away any time too soon.

https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html